# Django: Hiding the empty radio button option but still allowing it not to be null

Tags: django, radiobuttonlist

I have a large model that I use over multiple pages. I made each page a separate form in my forms.py file. On some of the later form pages I include radio buttons. Based on what I've seen around Google, the only way to hide the empty radio button option is to make the radio button list required. In my case I did this the following way in my model: `enlistment_date_known = models.CharField(max_length=10, choices=BOOL_CHOICES, blank=False, default=None)`

The problem is that these radio buttons are on my fourth page of my form, so when I submit the first page of my form, I get the following error:

```
('23000', "[23000] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Cannot 
insert the value NULL into column 'enlistment_date_known', table 
'LSPIntake_lonesoldier'; column does not allow nulls. INSERT fails. (515) 
(SQLExecDirectW); [23000] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server][SQL 
Server]The statement has been terminated. (3621)")
```

Is there a way to allow the value of my radio buttons to be null in the database but still hide the first, blank option?
Maybe by making the radio buttons required in the form instead of the model?

Answer (score 0):

I got it!

I just added `null=True` in addition to the other parameters.
Now the field declaration in the model looks like this:

```
enlistment_date_known = models.CharField(max_length=10, choices=BOOL_CHOICES, blank=False, null=True, default=None)
```

If anyone can explain this a little that would be appreciated. Not sure I fully understand the difference between blank and null.